# If group G is generated by a subset of commutative elements in G is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let G be a group that is generated by a subset $A$ where each element in $A$ is commutative to the other. As in, $\forall a,b\in A\colon ab=ba$. Prove that $G$ is abelian.

How can one approach this question?

I tried defining $C_A = \{\,x \in G \mid \forall z \in A\colon xz=zx\, \}$, then trying to prove that $C_A$ is a group and thus $C_A=G$ so every element in $G$ is commutative to all elements in $A$ but I am not sure that $C_A$ is a group as I could not prove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good idea. So is $C_A$ a group?

- $C_A$ is not empty because $1\in C_A$ (I was tempted to write "because $A\subseteq C_A$", nbut $A$ may be empty!)
- $x\in C_A$ implies $x^{-1}\in C_A$: Indeed for $z\in A$ we have $xz=za$ and hence $zx^{-1}=x^{-1}z$.
- If $x,y\in C_A$ then $xy\in C_A$: Indeed, if $z\in A$ then $xyz=xzy=zxy$.

Hence $C_A$ is indeed a subgroup of $G$ and also contains $A$, hence equals $G$.

Answer (score 1):

Every element of $G$ has the form $a_1a_2a_3\cdots a_n$ where $a_i\in A$.

It's easy to see that under your assumption,
$$(a_1a_2\cdots a_n)\cdot (a_1'a_2'\cdots a_n') = (a_1'a_2'\cdots a_n')\cdot (a_1a_2\cdots a_n)$$
(Your assumption lets you freely move the $a_i,a_i'$ around however you wish.)

Comment: The first paragraph should be “Every element of $G$ has the form $a_1a_2a_3\dots a_n$, where $a_i\in A$ or $a_i^{-1}\in A$”. One can show that $A'=A\cup A^{-1}$ also enjoys the same property as $A$ and conclude as you do, because now the elements of $G$ can be described as products of elements of $A'$. Your initial statement is true for finite groups, but not in general for infinite groups (think to $G=\mathbb{Z}$ and $A=\{1\}$).